# Reading Performance counters from Azure Cloud Service - Load Test

Tags: azure, load-testing, azure-cloud-services, azure-connect

I try to create a load test for a Azure hosted Web Service, but I am not able to connect to the Azure Cloud Service in order to collect the counters.
How can we connect to Azure cloud service from local machine or from any machine ?

I have tried to use the cloud service name, the VIP, but no luck.

Error: Cannot read counters from the machine 'xyz'.

Note: I am able to do RDC to the same cloud service.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to get performance counters from the machines you could configure Application Insights on your roles and collect them as part of your cloud load test.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/04/07/get-application-performance-data-during-load-runs-with-visual-studio-online.aspx
This link would give you an idea on how to do it.

Let me know if you have more queries. Above link should also help you in getting help from the product team.

Thanks!
Ranga

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this question - 
this can be done by configuring the IP addresses of the Virtual machine instances of your webservice (webrole / worker role) - in the load test's performance counter collection section. Your load test controller would have to be in the same subnet as of your application as well. This will help collect all perfmon data (including application's custom performance counters).